# JavaPOS Applet and Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, applet, javapos

I have a RoR web app that I would like to add some functionality to.  I want this app to be able to communicate with POS devices (cash drawer, printer).  I believe the best way to accomplish this would be to embed a signed Java Applet.  My plan is to add a bit of javascript that will send signals to the applet telling it when to print, open the cash drawer, etc.  The Java Applet will use the JavaPOS standards.

Questions:

1) Does this sound like a reasonable way to handle my situation?

2) Are there any applets like this available (whether opensource or commercially) that I could plug in?  Or am I better off just writing the applet myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Sure :)

2) Would likely depend on the POS you're targeting, whether it supports the JavaPOS standard, whether it has its own API etc...